# SQL Server: WHILE Within SELECT?

Tags: datetime, while-loop, sql-server-2012, subquery, reportbuilder3.0

As part of a report built through SQL Server 2012's Report Builder, I'm trying to measure the amount of time it has "officially" taken workers to do various tasks. In my Task table, I  have a Task Created datetime field, a Task Resolved datetime field, and I also have other tables for their clocking on/off times which I'm able to take data from.

I only want to measure in terms of the time during which they're supposed to have been working. So it doesn't include the overnight periods where they're not at work, which means it's not as simple as

```
DATEDIFF(minutes,TaskCreated,TaskResolved).
```

One way I've found to do it is to work out how many hours they've taken each day as separate fields, and sum those fields:

```
Created          |Resolved         |Day1time|Day2time |Day3time |TotalTime
14/04/2015 20:00 |16/04/2015 10:00 |01:00:00|12:00:00 |01:00:00 |14:00:00
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how long it could take to finish a certain job to account for this, so I don't know how many fields would need using, but the code would obviously be repetitive and therefore terrible especially if jobs could take a month or more to complete.

As someone more familiar with programming languages like Java and C++ than SQL, it seems to me this would be better done as a function with creation and resolution as parameters, a loop going through each day, and a variable incrementing that day's downtime. Unfortunately, it seems I don't have the permissions to create even temporary functions, so I'm wondering **is it possible to do a while loop to calculate the time within a Select statement?** I've tried to do this, but the code validator says it's invalid.

Sorry I don't have any code to help explain what I'm trying to do at the moment, as I'm away from my work PC, but eventually I'd like something like this:

```
Created          | Resolved         | Time Taken | Priority | Worker
01/01/2015 12:00 | 01/01/2015 13:00 | 01:00:00   | A        | C Forbes
02/03/2015 20:00 | 03/03/2015 11:00 | 03:00:00   | B        | J Flansburgh
31/05/2015 18:50 | 01/05/2015 10:50 | 00:10:00   | D        | E Idle
14/04/2015 20:00 | 16/04/2015 10:00 | 14:00:00   | D        | A Ng
```

*C Forbes - Standard job - datediff would work here*

*J Flansburgh - Worker finishes at 21:00 weekdays, and starts at 09:00, so 1 hour on day 1 + 2 hours on day 2 = 3 hours total*

*E Idle - Finishes at 19:00 on Sundays, and finished the job before (s)he was officially supposed to start on Monday. 10 minutes on Sunday the 31st, 0 minutes on Monday the 1st = 10 minutes*

*A Ng: Finishes at 21:00 weekdays, and starts at 09:00... 1 hour on the 14th+12 hours on the 15th+1 hour on the 16th = 14 hours total*

Another idea I've had while typing this question out is to do a while loop, taking one line at a time out of a table, working out the time from that individual line, then appending each line to a new table. Would this be better?

Thanks in advance for anyone who tries to help.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it depends on the content in your other table that contains the on/off times. Assuming you can do a join between the two tables based on the task (and worker?) I think you should be able to do something like:

```
SELECT tasks.Id, tasks.Created, tasks.Resolved,  SUM(DATEDIFF(minutes,timesheet.end, timesheet.start) as [Time Taken], tasks.Priority, tasks.Worker
FROM tasks
   INNER JOIN timesheet on tasks.Id = timesheet.TaskId and tasks.Worker = timesheet.Worker
GROUP BY tasks.Id, tasks.Created, tasks.Resolved, tasks.Priority, tasks.Worker
```

Comment: There are really a few reports I'm doing which have variations on this problem. With the ones directly relating to engineers, they all work the same shift pattern, which is only different on Sundays, so I've been using a case with datepart formula to check if Sunday, and work from there.The first report I had to do was based on access into places, with a table set up for a week eg. ... Thursday 09:00 17:00, Friday 09.00 17:00, Saturday 10:00 20:00, Sunday Closed Closed. On my mobile now, sorry about formatting.